# ¿Cómo organizar las rutas en Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario y requiere un *autocomplete* y *selects* pero  en las rutas; cuando voy a guardar me sale un error.

Mi código:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #Autocomplete          
  resources :reuniones do
    get :autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname, :on => :collection
  end

  #selects
  resources :reuniones do
    get :select_region, on: :collection
    get :select_ciudad, on: :collection
    get :select_planta, on: :collection
  end
end
```

O de esta manera:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #Autocomplete  y selects juntos        
  resources :reuniones do
    get :autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname, :on => :collection
    get :select_region, on: :collection
    get :select_ciudad, on: :collection
    get :select_planta, on: :collection
  end
end
```

**Ya  esta  asi**

```
resources :reuniones do
  collection do
    get :autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname
    get :select_region
    get :select_ciudad
    get :select_planta
  end
end
```

Me sale otro error: se bloquea pantalla

muestra el autocomplete

**log**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
reunion.rb

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :centro_costo

  def centro_costo_fullname
    centro_costo.fullname if centro_costo
  end

  def centro_costo_fullname=(fullname)
    self.centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by_fullname(fullname) unless fullname.blank?
  end
end
```

reuniones_controller.rb

```
autocomplete  :centro_costo, :fullname, :full => true, :column_name => 'fullname'

# GET /reuniones
# GET /reuniones.json
def index
  @reuniones = Reunion.all
  @negocios = Negocio.all
end

def select_region
  rs = Region.where(:negocio_id => params[:idnegocio]).order('nombre').all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
  end
end

def select_ciudad
  rs = Ciudad.where(:region_id => params[:idregion]).order('nombre').all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
  end
end

def select_planta
  rs = Planta.where(:ciudad_id => params[:idciudad]).order('nombre').all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
  end
end

def new
  Time.zone = 'America/Bogota' 
  @reunion = Reunion.new(fecha_entrega: Time.zone.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
  @reunion.detalles_reuniones.build
  @negocios = Negocio.all #para javascript
end

# GET /reuniones/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /reuniones
# POST /reuniones.json
def create
  @reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @reunion.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'Reunion was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reunion }
    else
   @negocios = Negocio.all
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ya checaste http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html ?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el error completo?

Comment: hola, el  es el error que muestra  pero ese es el select

Comment: Has agregado los elementos en los que imagino se produce el error, pero no el error que obtienes. Ese lo puedes ver en tus logs o en la consola. ¿Podrías agregar esa información?

Comment: @Gerry ya esta el log gracias.

Comment: @juangomez Al parecer la variable `@negocios` no tiene nada (i.e. es `nil`); ¿puedes mostrar tu controllador `ReunionesController`?

Comment: @Gerry  ya  esta  listo, gracias

Comment: Has agregado el modelo, pero para encontrar el error necesitamos el controlador, lo debes tener en `app/controllers/reuniones_controller.rb`.

Comment: @Gerry ya esta listo  estoy un poco cansado llevo 12 horas camellandole a esto y no he podido, gracias

Comment: ¿Ese es el código completo de tu controlador? No veo la acción `create` (en donde se genera el error) en ningún lado.

Comment: @Gerry  ya  esta  como me dijo.gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... estoy haciendo un formulario y requiere un *autocomplete* y
>   *selects* pero  en las rutas; cuando voy a guardar me sale un error.

El error se debe a que no existe la variable `@negocios` en tu acción `create`, la cual es necesaria para poder ejecutar la línea `format.html { render :new }` de esa acción.

Esta línea se ejecuta cuando alguna validación falla al momento de crear el registro en la BD (i.e. no se crea) y tu acción indica que se muestre nuevamente la vista `new`, en la cual necesitas la variable `@negocios` para poder generar tu `select_tag` de `negocio`.

En el log se puede ver que la validación falla en algún punto con estas líneas:

```
(0.1ms) begin transaction
(0.0ms) rollback transaction
```

En la línea siguiente puedes ver como se ejecuta la línea `format.html { render :new }` de tu acción `create`:

```
Rendering reuniones/new.html.erb within layouts/application
```

Para arreglar ese error necesitas crear la variable `@negocios` tal como lo haces en la acción `new`, por ejemplo, así se vería tu acción `create`:

```
def create
  @reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @reunion.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'Reunion was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reunion }
    else
      @negocios = Negocio.all

      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

> Cómo organizar las rutas en Ruby on Rails?

Tu segunda opción es correcta, considerando que tengas las acciones correspondientes en tu controlador; sin embargo podrías optimizar un poco tu código utilizando un bloque en `collection`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #Autocomplete  y selects juntos           
  resources :reuniones do
    collection do
      get :autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname
      get :select_region
      get :select_ciudad
      get :select_planta
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: hola Edité el problema arriba

Comment: por ejemplo el  , :on => :collection y el  on: :collection  donde queda.

Comment: @juangomez `on` ya no es necesario pues todas tus rutas las estás declarando dentro de un bloque en `collection`, lo que es equivalente a poner `on: :collection` a cada una.

Comment: @juangomez Por cierto, `on: :collection` y `:on => :collection` hacen exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: @juangomez He actualizado la respuesta con la solución al error que te muestra el log.

Comment: Hola  @Gerry me sale el  error  del auto complete, coloque  log y el error,  gracias.

Comment: @juangomez Al parecer este es un error diferente, por lo que lo mejor sería abrir una pregunta nueva con este error (y regresar el error original a esta pregunta) y marcar esta respuesta como aceptada (dando clic a la paloma) pues, al parecer, sí resolvió el error. El problema de cambiar el error en la pregunta es que esta cambia de sentido y la respuesta que se dio deja de ser vigente. En esa nueva pregunta pon el log y el código del error (en este caso `centro_costo.rb` pues al parecer hay un error en el nombre de la clase y `reunion.rb`, archivo que genera el error.

Comment: @juangomez En cuanto al error como tal, parece que estás llamando mal a tu clase en `reunion.rb`, asumiendo que tu clase se llama `CentroCosto` cambia esta línea: `Centro_costo.find_by_fullname(fullname) unless fullname.blank?` por esta `CentroCosto.find_by_fullname(fullname) unless fullname.blank?`.

Comment: hola , pero se  bloquea la pantalla en el log dice lo de arriba.gracias

Comment: ,hola , pero se bloquea la pantalla en el log dice lo de arriba.gracias,@Gerry

Comment: @juangomez ¿A qué te refieres con "se bloquea"?, ¿cuál es el comportamiento?

Comment: no deja guardar sale en error  pero no muestra en la pantalla.gracias.@Gerry

Comment: @juangomez Por favor genera una nueva pregunta incluyendo este problema, con el código relacionado a ese problema (ya no incluyas información relacionada al problema de esta pregunta). Será más sencillo y otros usuarios probablemente también brinden ayuda.

Comment: y  como la pongo

Comment: @juangomez Es un post nuevo simplemente. Así como abriste esta pregunta inicialmente.